# table automatically centering the text

Tags: html, css

I made a table with some text and it iss automatically centering it vertically. Example:

[image]

How can I make the text to go from the top? I mean the normal way, you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align)

> The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an
>   inline or table-cell element.

**html**

```
<table class="someClass">
    <tr>
        <td>Hello World</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
.someClass td { vertical-align: top; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
....
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```